# Windows Process Memory Viewer/Extracting data from a chart program

Tags: windows, memory, automation

I've got a windows app which draws charts from data points but there is no way to export the data points into a portable format. I tried using AutoIt to access the form controls values but they were concealed by draw functions. I thought with a memory viewer I might be able to view whatever container is storing the chart values, and extract it that way. However, I tried PrcView and HeapMemView but I was disappointed by their search features. I could not locate anything meaningful with these programs because the memory space was segmented so much that I could not tell where the chart data was stored. Does anyone have a suggestion for how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly try to find another source for the data; it'll possibly be a lot easier.

If there is no choice and this is something that I had to do then I would probably look at [hooking](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx) the API and catching the Win32 MoveTo / LineTo, and recording / processing them, or possibly [API Spying](http://www.internals.com/articles/apispy/apispy.htm); either way it will be a lot of effort.